# how to link an image in html

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

i'm a beginner in web design and i have this folder and inside are the html, css, and images that needs to be submitted to my prof and i'm not sure if the images i linked on the html will be seen because the location of the image i linked there was the location of the image on my pc. for example i put

```
<body>
    <img src ="C:\Users\project\pic.jpg">
</body>
```

Will my prof be able to see it? If not, is there another way how? Thanks!

Comment: Time to learn about [file paths](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-file-paths/) . Hint: don't use paths starting from a drive letter.

Comment: Since the folder is what is being sent make sure to have all assets and paths within the scope of that folder. Also leave an upvote/accept any answers below you deem to have sufficiently answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, they won't be able to see the image.

Create a new folder in the  project folder you already have. Image folders on the web are often named - *img* or *images*

Copy your picture to it.

change `<img src ="C:\Users\project\pic.jpg">`

to `<img src ="images/pic.jpg">`

Zip your project folder and send the zip.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/yourfolder/Users/project/pic.jpg"/>
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your image before use in html file otherwise you cannot able to share your product with image